# Choosing encoder for payloads in metasploit

Tags: metasploit, encoding

I noticed that every payload (for example bind_tcp) in metasploit comes with defaut encoder.( shikata_ga_nai for bind_tcp).

Is there a way in metasploit to manualy choose encoding for payloads or way to cancel encoding at all?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use it from the command line with `msfencode` if you're generating shellcode or from within msfconsole using the `set` and `show encoders` commands. You can find more details about this here: http://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Msfconsole_Commands