# Encode metasploit payload with ContextEncoding?

Tags: exploit, metasploit

Using metasploit I generated an exploit `exploit/windows/fileformat/ms14_017_rtf` for windows 7 with `windows/shell_reverse_tcp payload`. In show advanced, I use option `EnableContextEncoding true` and it's working well. Then I create a stand alone module, that generate malicious rtf document. Now I want add encode function in my module. What the module uses the option `EnableContextEncoding true`? Is this `x86/shikata_ga_nai.rb` or other? I need standalone code, which encode my buffer (shellcode)? I can't find it.

Comment: Yeah you can also list all available encodings in the advanced options. Use `show encoders` https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/78594/choosing-encoder-for-payloads-in-metasploit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't really want Context Encoding.  Context Encoding is a technique for generating self-decrypting shellcode that will only work on the intended machine. It is off by default because it requires knowing specific information about the victim that you usually do not have unless you have already compromised that machine.

`msfvenom` can take shellcode on stdin and output encoded shellcode on stdout like so:

```
cat payload.bin | msfvenom -p - -a x86 --platform windows -e x86/shikata_ga_nai -f raw > encoded.bin
```